# Função C++ Erro: cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++

quadrada cannot be used as a function. Alguem pode me dizer como consertar?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
struct leituras{
  float vetor[1000];
  int n;
}n1;
int quadrados(leituras n1, int i, float desvio_qualquer, float *quadrados);
int main ()
{
    int i;
    float soma, media, desvio, desvio_qualquer, soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras,x,quadrados;
    cout << "Programa para calcular a media das leituras de um experimento e o desvio da media, o programa trabalha com no maximo 1000(mil) leituras.\n";
    cout << "Digite o numero de leituras que seram inseridas no programa, sendo inteiro não negativas e diferente de zero e menores ou igual a 1000,e use pontos e não virgulas para expressar numeros decimais :\n";
    cin >> (n1.n);
    if(n1.n != 0) {
        for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++)  {
            cout << "Digite as leituras:\n ";
            cin >> (n1.vetor[i]);
            }
        for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++)  {
            soma = soma+n1.vetor[i];
}
        media=soma/n1.n;
        for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++)  
        {
            desvio_qualquer = n1.vetor[i] - media;
            quadrados(n1.n, i, desvio_qualquer, &quadrados);
            soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras = soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras + quadrados;
    }
        x=pow(n1.n,-1);
        desvio=sqrt(x*soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras);
        cout << "A media é: " << media << " \n E o desvio é: " << desvio << endl;

}
    else {
        cout << "Digite a leitura:\n ";
        cin >> (n1.vetor[1]);
        cout << "A media é: " << n1.vetor[1] << " E o desvio é 0(zero)" << endl;
}


  return 0;
}

int quadrados(leituras n1, int i, float desvio_qualquer, float *quadrados) {

    for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++){
        *quadrados = desvio_qualquer*desvio_qualquer;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código possui os seguintes erros:

1. Falta uma chave no final do código }
2. Na linha 32 você está passando um parâmetro incorreto

Seu código:

```
quadrados(n1.n, i, desvio_qualquer, &quadrados);
```

Correto:

```
quadrados(n1, i, desvio_qualquer, &quadrado);
```

Repare que eu mudei o nome do terceiro parâmetro, faça isso também na declaração pois o compilador está se confundindo entre sua struct e a variável float.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Como você é usuário novo talvez não saiba. Ao lado da minha resposta tem um sinal de "certo / v" que pode marcar caso considere a resposta como solução de seu problema. Isso serve para incentivar quem responde as perguntas e ficar registrado que seu problema foi solucionado